# Is there a Lebesgue measurable set that is not an open set up to a set of measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Two theorems in a first course on measure theory are:

1. $ E \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ is measurable if and only if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an open set $O$ with $E \subseteq O$ and $m^*(O-E)<\epsilon$
2. $ E \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ is measurable if and only if there exists a $G_\delta$ set $G$ with $E \subseteq G$ and $m^*(G-E)=0$. i.e. every measurable set is $G_\delta$ up to a set of measure zero.

My question is: can (1) be improved to say that $ E \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ is measurable if and only if there exists an open set $O$ with $E \subseteq O$ and $m^*(O-E)=0$? If not, how would one construct an example of a measurable set $E$ that is not an open set up to a set of measure zero?

Comment: The words "$E$ is an open set up to a set of measure zero" would normally be understood to mean that there is an open set $O$, not necessarily a superset of $E$, such that the symmetric difference $(E\setminus O)\cup(O\setminus E)$ has measure zero. There are examples of measurable sets which do not satisfy this weaker condition, but they are not quite so trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe such examples are plentiful. Here are two easy ones:

Consider any non-empty measure $0$ set. Non-empty open sets have strictly positive measure.

Consider any non-empty, bounded, closed interval. Any open interval (and thus any open set) that contains it must be strictly wider.

Comment: Thanks! I feel pretty stupid now :/

Comment: @bof You're right. I feel a little bit silly now too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you also want a measurable set of measure $>0$. At the risk of reposting:

Remove around every rational $r_n \in [0,1]$ an open  segment $I_n$ of size $\epsilon_n$, with $\sum \epsilon_n < 1$. Now take

$$A = [0,1] \backslash \bigcup_n I_n$$

and see that $m(A)>0$ and $m(A\cap U) < m(U)$ for every open subset of $[0,1]$.